# Облачный рабочий стол (DaaS)

Tags: установка, сеть, windows, облако

Идея такая вообщем: арендовать некую облачный сервер DaaS (desktop as service) и создать там пользователей 10 штук, например. ОC выбираем Windows и +MS office 2010 Standard. И чтобы этим юзерам открыть доступ приложениям, который я установил (настроил) на "облаке". Интересно, а как установить туда игры, GTA, CS, etc.

Возможно ли это? Какие проблемы с VGA и т.д.? Что мы имеем в резултате этого всего:

**Плюсы:** не надо беспокоиться насчет обслуживания машин, программ, ит.д. Так как мы арендуем, и только за аренду платим. В итоге хотелось бы получить рабочую data-center интернет кафе (в том то и дело).

**Минусы:** нужно будет скоростной интернет, ограниченная возможность к системе.Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Жду отзывы! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [IPGuard: управление компьютерным клубом](http://ipguard.org.ua/).

Answer (score 0):

Какие игры???

Виртуальный рабочий стол! Это не локальный компьютер. Нужна такая система для мобильности офиса и только для тех людей которые в этом нуждаются. Т.е. постоянные командировки большого кол-ва манагеров, а им постоянно нужен доступ к инфе, для этого и делают DAAS.

Какой смысл ставить туда игры, вы что?

```
Плюсы: не надо беспокоиться насчет обслуживание машин, программ, ит.д. Так как мы арендуем, и только за аренду платим. В итоге хотелось бы получить рабочую data-center интернет кафе(в том то и дело).
```

Ха. По поводу беспокойств. Постоянно будете следить за сервером, чтобы на нем не слетали настройки. т.к. за этими серверами следите только вы! и никто более.

И очень советую писать по-русски, а не

> В итоге хотелось бы получить рабочую data-centerэто бредово звучит.

Идея не айс! В данном контексте просто деньги на ветер.

Comment: ладно,согласен.А что бы предложили чтобы реализовать интернет кафе(или клуб) с 10 раб.станциями ???

Comment: Ну поставить сервер, на сервере установить нужное ПО. И сделать локальную сеть на 10 машинок.у а про доступ в инет и прочее это уже к программам по трафику и пользователям, все зависит от выбранной ОС.+ хороший инет канал.

Comment: что скажете насчет тонькие клиенты? есть ли тк поддерживающие игры?

Comment: Вообще коммент не понял.

Comment: хотел сказать, вместо 10 машин ставить так называемые тонькие клиенты? Просто я сам не работал с ними, но хотелось бы попробовать.Незнаю,стоит ли ,или нет  купить их.

Comment: > тонькие клиенты терминалы?

Answer (score 0):

10 компьютеров оптимальный вариант.

Comment: как вы узнали?? ))Насчет тонькие клиенты или как еще, терминалы какие идеи? играть можно?

Comment: нет, тонкие клиенты не подойдут. Терминалка то же, т.к. там разделяемые ресурсы одной машины.  Вы почитайте сначала про эти вещщи.